# How to encode object like list of dict which contains unicode key or value to utf8?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Is there any easy way to convert object which contains unicode string into utf8?

for example:

```
before = [ 
    u'labelset': {u'labelset_id': 80L, u'labelset_name': u'\u6d17\u8863\u6a5f'},
    u'labelset': {u'labelset_id': 81L, u'labelset_name': u'\u6d17\u8863\u6a5f'},
    u'labelset': {u'labelset_id': 82L, u'labelset_name': u'\u6d17\u8863\u6a5f'},
]

after = [
    'labelset': {labelset_id: 80L, labelset_name: 'test'},
    'labelset': {labelset_id: 81L, labelset_name: 'test'},
    'labelset': {labelset_id: 81L, labelset_name: 'test'},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.* there are two types of string:

```
str (sequence of bytes)
unicode (sequence of unicode code points)
```

To transform unicode to str, it is needed to specify the rule (what bytes are represent particular unicode point). This rule is called **encoding**. So, to transform unicode to str, using `utf8` encoding, you need to use `encode` method:

```
>>> u'\u6d17\u8863\u6a5f'.encode('utf8')
'\xe6\xb4\x97\xe8\xa1\xa3\xe6\xa9\x9f'
```

The result will be a sequence of bytes, that can be saved, for example, to text file.

To convert back str to unicode, you need to know, what rules were applied during convertion from unicode to str. In current case this rule was `utf8` encoding. For this purpose use `decode` method:

```
>>> '\xe6\xb4\x97\xe8\xa1\xa3\xe6\xa9\x9f'.decode('utf8')
u'\u6d17\u8863\u6a5f'
```

Here is a good [presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) about python strings and encodings

Comment: Thanks for reply. Learned from your explanation. Is there any api I can call to convert object which contains unicode key into str? Link pprint.pprint, it only print out unicode sqeuqnce. Thanks.